# TCP Server on LwIP raw API - question about tcp_close and accept callback

Tags: c, tcp, lwip

I'm using [this](https://github.com/dreamcat4/lwip/blob/master/contrib/apps/tcpecho_raw/echo.c) simple echo-server as an example.
It creates a listening connection, receives a packet, sends it back and then closes the connection.

In the initialization function, accept callback is registered in lwip like this:

```
void
echo_init(void)
{
    echo_pcb = tcp_new();
    ...
    echo_pcb = tcp_listen(echo_pcb);
    tcp_accept(echo_pcb, echo_accept);
```

Connection is closed by the server after each echo session, like this:

```
void
echo_close(struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, struct echo_state *es)
{
  tcp_arg(tpcb, NULL);
  tcp_sent(tpcb, NULL);
  tcp_recv(tpcb, NULL);
  tcp_err(tpcb, NULL);
  tcp_poll(tpcb, NULL, 0);

  if (es != NULL)
  {
    mem_free(es);
  }  
  tcp_close(tpcb);
```

[Documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__tcp__raw.html#ga87093e137fcc53ea82a134a3f5b33623) says that `tcp_close` will free pcb structure. All of the callbacks that are used for tcp server are registered with this structure.

But when client sends new packet and starts a new connection, accept callback is called! Even though `tcp_accept(echo_pcb, echo_accept);` (i.e. callback registration) is done only once in the `init` function and that `echo_pcb` structure is already freed after `tcp_close`.

So I'm confused. Why all the other callbacks are registered multiple times but accept is registered only once? Is it okay to do it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so according to this [answer](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lwip-users/2018-10/msg00001.html) to the same question on the lwip mailing list, that is correct behaviour. tcp_accept registers callback for a port and it won't be unregistered when tcp_close is called.

Comment: accept creates a new connection. It is that new connection you are closing, not the listening socket..

Comment: @nos basically, yes